# подтягивать название из заголовка при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Постараюсь обяснить.... есть разметка с каталогом товара, надо чтоб при клике на кнопку подхвачивалось название из h2 разметка повторяется с разными h2....при клике на кнопку всплывает модальное окно MagnificPopup, название с кнопки подтягивается в форму (ниже добавлю скрипт) как его дополнить чтоб добавлялось и название товара, то есть h2

```
<div class="card-product"> 
    <div class="img-wrap"> 
        <div class="demo"> 

        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="info-wrap"> 
        <h2>Портмоне HR0001B</h2> 

        <div class="buttons-wrap"> 
            <a href="#callback" class="buttons">*****</a> 
        </div>              
    </div> 
</div> 


$(".card-product a").click(function () {
$("#callback h4").html($(this).text());
}).magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    mainClass: "mfp-form"
});
```

Comment: где вышеозначенная кнопка?

Comment: тут кнопка ссылка видимо

Comment: <div class="buttons-wrap"> 
            <a href="#callback" class="buttons">*****</a> 
        </div>

Comment: `$(this).closest(".info-wrap").find("h2").text()` - "Портмоне HR0001B"

Comment: неа...не срабатывает

Comment: а я говорю - срабатывает

Comment: @Igor он не знает куда вставить))

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее....поправил и заработало...учиться учиться и еще раз учиться мне надо...можна какието материалы=))))     $(".info-wrap a").click(function () { 
var a= $(this).closest(".info-wrap").find("h2").text(); 
$("#callback h4 ").html($(this).text()+"<br>"+a); 
}).magnificPopup({ 
type: 'inline', 
mainClass: "mfp-form" 
});

Comment: @Dom - Хм, материалы... Я, в основном, использую англоязычный StackOverflow и http://api.jquery.com/. Успехов в программировании!